# Nodemon- waiting for file changes before starting... I have tried killing all the commands and restarting nodemon but still doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, nodemon

*I haven't made any changed it was working fine but suddenly today when i started by project and tried nodemon it doesn't work and app crashes. nom start is still working for me.*

```
 This is the error i get when i try running nodemon

        [nodemon] 2.0.20
        [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
        [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
        [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
        [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
        node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
          throw err;
          ^
        
        Error: Cannot find module '/Users/abhayashta/Desktop/Week5/index.js'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
            at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
            at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
            at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
          code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
          requireStack: []
        }
        [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
        ^C%
```

Comment: are you trying to run this from `Week5` folder where there isn't index.js file there?

Comment: no i have index.js file but its inside routes folder in week 5. Also i tried placing it out of the routes folder and tried running nodemon but it still shows the same error

Comment: but if i run npm start it runs perfectly fine

Comment: Where is `package.json` and what `start` scripts do?

Comment: package.json is in the week 5 folder and i'm not sure what you are asking about start scripts?

Comment: inside `package.json` there is a section `scripts`. what does `start` script do?

Comment: that's implimenting node ./server.js

Comment: Thanks for helping guys, I figured out a new way of doing it, if your app crashes just like that after running nodemon in your terminal. end the nodemon with contol+ c and then try "npm start" it should work but in this case you just need to restart every time you make a change in your file.

Comment: But i would surely appreciate if anybody can suggest me why my nodemon is crashing.

Comment: @PowerRanger you didn't show your `pacakge.json` we don't know what your script do

Comment: "*why my nodemon is crashing*"  because probably you are starting it from a folder where it can't find an `index.js`, like the error is telling you. It's hard to give any hints because you don't give enough details. For instance, what exact command you use to start your server, in which folder you execute it,  what your `npm start` executes and where the respective `package.json` is located ...